# How to get Timer value of iphone in iwatch as Notification?

Tags: ios, timer, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

Can you please guide me how to send timer value in iWatch as Notification?

For example : Exercise time will be send to iwatch Notification ?
is there any Official Way ?

Comment: i done with image and label to iwatch from iphone. but not getting idea about timer. is it possible to send timer value to iwatch ?

Comment: Yes its possible. There is a replyblock that you can use since xCode 8.2. You can pass values back and forth from WatchKit Extension to app. Checkout "openParentApplication:reply:" https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply: There is also MMWormHole at Github.